# Access VPN established on another subnet within network

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, symantec

I have three locations: A is a host with T1 internet connection, B and C are point-to-point with A. Each location also has their on default gateway.

A, B, C all have different subnets:

A: 10.30.7.x
B: 10.30.9.x
C: 192.168.2.x

There is an Ipsec VPN connected to **192.168.26.x** by a Symantec Gateway Security 320 (subnet A). But I am unable to ping an address on the other side of the vpn from any computer on subnets B and C.

I need to know how to have one computer (WinXP) from B and one from C be able to utilize the VPN connection made on A.

Is is possible to split-tunnel my Symantec, or create routes through command prompt on the machines needing the VPN connection?

Answer (score 3):

The routers at sites B and C need to learn how to reach 192.168.26.x either by putting in a static route or having router A advertise it using a routing protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot my login info when I asked this question!!

Added each subnet to routing of Symantec, didn't fix the issue.

The routers at B and C are owned/managed by ISP, so I have called them asking to add static route, and they are "looking into the issue".

Other than not being able to ping this VPN from subnets B and C, having no connectivity/passing traffic issues.
Thanks for your help, Tom